# Return focus to spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm running some Google Scripts linked to buttons on my Google Spreadsheet.  After clicking the button to run the script, even though the spreadsheet is still being viewed and the selected cell is still visible, focus on the spreadsheet window is lost.  I have to click the window to return focus.

This sounds like a very similar question to [the one asked by robodog21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231956/selecting-highlighting-next-adjacent-cell-in-row-after-function-has-been-execute/47234059#47234059).  Ed Nelson's solution involving a sidebar with buttons executing the HTML command google.script.host.editor.focus() works well, but I'd really rather not involve a sidebar.  I'd prefer to stick with my existing buttons if possible.  These are inserted on the spreadsheet as a Google Drawing and then linked to the appropriate Javascript function.

As robodog21 indicated, I am also quite new to Javascript and HTML.  I found the following help in Google Apps Script:

> **Moving browser focus in G Suite**
>
> To switch focus in the user's browser from a dialog or sidebar back to the Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms editor, simply call the method google.script.host.editor.focus(). This method is particularly useful in combination with the Document service methods Document.setCursor(position) and Document.setSelection(range).

However I have not figured out how to implement this due to my limited familiarity with HTML.

I have not been able to find a solution in Stack Overflow related specifically to Google Apps Scripts and don't know enough (yet!) to modify other solutions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311557/moving-browser-focus-in-google-apps-using-ui-service-api)) to suit my needs.  I would appreciate someone clarifying how to apply a solution to my situation.

Answer (score 4):

After reading Rubén's answer and resigning myself to using a sidebar, I kept playing around with my scripts and realized that all it takes to return focus to the spreadsheet is simply opening and closing a sidebar.  The minimum HTML seems to be:

```
<html>
  <body onload="google.script.host.close()">
  </body>
</html>
```

This is called in a JS function:

```
function sidebarCreator() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showSidebar(html)
}
```

I realize this implementation is a little messy in that it pulls up a sidebar which I don't actually want and then immediately closes it.  However, it accomplishes what I want with no other changes needed to my existing buttons and functions, so I'm fairly happy.  If anyone knows a better method to achieve this result please let me know.  Thanks to Rubén for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: In case someone is confused about the HTML part, go to File > New > HTML file, name it "Page" and paste the html code above.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for my application but may or may not be acceptable to OP:

Add something like the following line prior to range selection:

```
Browser.msgBox("Ready to add a Venue?",Browser.Buttons.Yes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an image/drawing on a Spreadsheet to call a script, it's not possible to programatically to set the focus on a spreadsheet cell or selection.

You could set the active cell or selection but not to set the focus on them.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313087/1595451) to [Moving browser focus in Google Apps using Ui Service API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26311557/1595451) (referred by the OP) implies the use of the HTML Service which works because a sidebar is being used.

Comment: I see - so the use of the sidebar is essential to the success of that method.  Well, maybe I'll have to see about making the sidebar work then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm a little late, but I was having the same problem and found this thread.  Also, this is my first post to stackoverflow, so be gentle.  :)

My issue was similar to the OP, in that I had a drawing bound to a script, and trying to use the arrow keys to change which cell had focus would no longer work after clicking the drawing to run the script.  After searching and failing to find a solution, I discovered that **if you simply hit the esc key** once right after running the script, focus is returned to the sheet and the arrow keys again work to change which cell has focus.  That's easy enough that it was no longer worth trying to find a programmatic solution.

Hope this workaround helps someone out there.